# Some doubts about how write RaspBian on SD card using dd command?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, headless

I am very new in RaspBerry Pi and I am trying to installa RaspBian on my SD.

So I have perform the following operations:

1) In the shell I have execute the following statment to copy RaspBian on my SD:

```
sudo dd if=2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/sdb bs=1024
```

and I have obtained the following output:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~/Scrivania/raspbian$ sudo dd if=2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/sdb bs=1024
2892800+0 record dentro
2892800+0 record fuori
2962227200 byte (3,0 GB) copiati, 1960,67 s, 1,5 MB/s
```

Is it ok?

2) The if I perform **fdisk -l** I obtain that I have 2 partitions:

```
Disco /dev/sdb: 7948 MB, 7948206080 byte
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 966 cilindri, totale 15523840 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x000981cb

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            8192      122879       57344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2          122880     5785599     2831360   83  Linux
```

**sdb1** that is a litle FAT32 patition and **sdb2** that is a largest Linux partition.

Is it ok? Why I still have a FAT32 partition? And where it put the RaspBian? On the Linux partition?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2962227200 byte (3,0 GB) copiati, 1960,67 s, 1,5 MB/s
```

1.5MB/s is a bit slow, you should have used `bs=10M` in your `dd` command.

the rest is fine too, my RPi also has 2 partitions:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

the `/boot` partition contains some stuff that gets the linux running (it's much easier to read FAT than correctly process ext3/ext4 partitions in the boot loader), the rest is ext4 -- that's where your Raspbian and your files live.

Comment: mmm, now I have some more doubts about what you say to me. 1) You say to me that 1,5 MB/s is slow. But what exactly represent this value? It only represent the speed used to write the SD this time or the speed of my SD when I will run RaspBian?

Comment: 1.5MB/s is the speed `dd` was able to achieve while writing your SD card, on the most contemporary cards it's supposed to be 2-5 times higher. when you use this card with your RPi, most likely you'll experience not the best performance possible. please, check if you SD card is class 10 or something similar.

Comment: yes my SD card is class 10. But the thing that I can't understand is what happen if now I use this card into my RPi. I will have low performance using the RPi or I had low performance only writing the RaspBian system on this card? If I will have low performance using RaspBian, why? The operating system is now written on the SD, why the speed that dd was able to achieve while wrot the operative system influence the use of the operative system in a second time?

Comment: basically, PC is faster and has more resources to write SD cards efficiently that a single-board computers. however, if your card is class 10, I would not worry much about this, plug it in and start using. maybe your sd card reader or usb connection was not up to the task.